# How can I update the right data by using id?

Tags: php

I can display first name, last name and the instrument they borrowed. There is a drop down if they want to change the instrument they borrowed. Why is my code not changing the instrument that the person is changing? What could be wrong in this code? Please help. I know my code is not agreeable to sql securement, this is just an activity. [database](https://github.com/patrickesguerra/sql)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","borrow");
$q="SELECT students.studentid,students.studfname,students.studlname,instruments.instrumentname, instruments.instrumentid from students INNER JOIN student_instrument ON students.studentid=student_instrument.id INNER JOIN instruments ON student_instrument.checkoutdate=instruments.dateacquired";


//SELECT students.studentid,instruments.instrumentid,students.studfname,students.studlname,instruments.instrumentname from
 //students INNER JOIN instruments ON students.studentid=instruments.instrumentid
$t="SELECT instrumentname from instruments where dateacquired='avail'";
$r=mysqli_query($con,$q);
$e=mysqli_query($con,$t);

while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
    $id=$result['instrumentid'];
    $studfname=$result['studfname'];
    $studlname=$result['studlname'];
    $instrumentname=$result['instrumentname'];

    echo $studfname." ".$studlname." ".$instrumentname." ";
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value='.$id.'>';
    echo '<select name="inst">';
    while($f=mysqli_fetch_array($e)){
    $avail=$f['instrumentname'];
    echo '<option>'.$avail.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"><br>';
}
 ?>
 </form>
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $id=$_POST['id'];
     $inst=$_POST['inst'];
     $p="UPDATE instruments SET instrumentname='$inst' WHERE id='$id'";
     $q=mysqli_query($con,$p);
     if($q){
         header('location:student.php');
     }
 }
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the last row is updated, not the first one

Comment: did you tried it?

Comment: where specifically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198772/discussion-between-dark-phoenix-and-andrea-manzi).

Answer (score 0):

Check the generated HTML code and look for the `<form>` and `</form>` tag. Currently you have a form similar like this:

```
<form action="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="5" />
    <input type="submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="8" />
    <input type="submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="9" />
    <input type="submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="11" />
    <input type="submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="21" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You generate only **one** form. When you submit that form you will send **all** the ids on the same field name "id". This means only the last id will be stored in `$_POST['id']`. This explains the "the last row is updated, not the first one".

To fix your problem you have to create individual forms so they will look similar to this:

```
<form action="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="5" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<form action="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="8" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<form action="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="9" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<form action="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="11" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<form action="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="21" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

So opening and closing the form must be happening inside the `while` loop.